# from PIL import _imaging problem, 3.6 running well and 3.7 not running

Tags: python-3.6, python-3.7

My OS is Linux Mint 19. I have several versions of Python 3.6, 3.7. My Pillow version is 5.1. I am trying to do `from PIL import _imaging` but I am getting a problem at 3.7 showing that I can not import it. As follow:

**ImportError: cannot import name '_imaging' from 'PIL' (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PIL/__init__.py)**

If I run from the terminal with Python 3.6 I am not getting this kind of problem.

Answer (score 1):

Did you install Pillow for the newer Python version?

`python3.7 -m pip install Pillow`

Comment: Yes, in addition. Running from the terminal I open Python 3.7 and I can do ```import PIL``` with no problems. The problem is appearing when I do ```from PIL import _imaging```. Python 3.7.5 to be more clear.

Comment: Are you sure you installed Pillow for 3.7? I had exactly the same problem (running Linux Mint) after running the above command it was fixed! Wat is your output running: `python3.7 -m pip freeze | grep Pillow` ?

Comment: This is my output **Pillow==5.1.0**

Comment: I fixed the problem already. ```sudo python3.7 -m pip uninstall Pillow``` then I install again using ```sudo python3.7 -m pip install Pillow```. Then I tried something that was working before, running under 3.6 and now is not working my logic. So, I can asume that before pip function install library for 3.6 to the dist-packages for both. I have to read about virtual environment, for sure the problem with a venv does not happened.

Comment: Okay, can you try: `python3.7 -m pip install -Iv Pillow==7.1.0` ?

Comment: Anyway, Thank you.